# Acces denied for user en localhost laragon

Tags: laravel

Me sale el siguiente error al querer registrar un usuario:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = xxxx@gmail.com)

Como puedo solucionarlo, he colocado clave al gestor heidisql que es de laragon por defecto, limpie cache, configure el .env con los datos correctos y sigue el mismo error.

Desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Lo he podido solucionar, en el archivo databease.php en database y username estaban como  homestead, lo que realice fue cambiarlo por forge y ahi me comenzó a funcionar la conexion y he podido registrar un usuario..

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
```